# ¿Cómo puedo convertir u obtener la duración media de la sesión de Google Analytics en una App de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics

El problema que tengo es que necesito obtener la duración media de la sesión en minutos ya que GA me devuelve decimales.

Este es mi código:

```
    //Obtengo el día actual
        $day = date('Y-m-d');
        //Obtengo la fecha que deseo que empieze
        $startDate = new \DateTime('2020-01-01');
        //Fecha en la que termina recibe la fecha actual
        $endDate = new \DateTime($day);
        //Obtiene la diferencia de la fecha actual
        $diferencia = $startDate->diff($endDate);
        //Obtiene los meses que han pasado
        $meses = ($diferencia->y * 12) + $diferencia->m;
      /* Duración media de sesión */
            $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration = Analytics::performQuery(
                Period::months($meses),
                'ga:avgSessionDuration',
                [
                    'ids' => 'ga:XXXXXXX',
                ]
            );
```

Como resultado obtengo el siguiente `237.3838383838384` cómo podria obtener el tiempo en si como en GA que te muestra por ejemplo 00:06:29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente la solución es esta:

```
//Obtengo el día actual
            $day = date('Y-m-d');
            //Obtengo la fecha que deseo que empieze
            $startDate = new \DateTime('2020-01-01');
            //Fecha en la que termina recibe la fecha actual
            $endDate = new \DateTime($day);
            //Obtiene la diferencia de la fecha actual
            $diferencia = $startDate->diff($endDate);
            //Obtiene los meses que han pasado
            $meses = ($diferencia->y * 12) + $diferencia->m;    
    /* Duración media de sesión */
                $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration = Analytics::performQuery(
                    Period::months($meses),
                    'ga:avgSessionDuration',
                    [
                        'ids' => 'ga:XXXXXXX',
                    ]
                );
                //dd($visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0]);
                /* $result = $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0]/60;
                dd($result); */
                $horas = floor($visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0] /3600);
                $minutos = floor(($visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0] - ($horas * 3600)) /60);
                $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration = $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0] - ($horas * 3600) - ($minutos * 60);

                dd($horas,$minutos, $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration);
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? O una edición a tu pregunta?

Comment: @JheymanMejia se me había olvidado añadir que era la solución, perdona.

Answer (score 0):

Si divides entre 60 te da los minutos luego que tengas los minutos con el date puedes transformarlo en horas, pero te recomiendo que lo pases a minutos, con eso el dato se ve más claro

Comment: Voy a probarlo!. Acabo de dividir el resultado por 60 y obtengo `3.9563973063973`

Comment: Finalmente he optado por este método que también comentadas: `$horas = floor($visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0] /3600);`  `$minutos = floor(($visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0] - ($horas * 3600)) /60);`  `$visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration = $visitSummaryAverageSessionDuration['rows'][0][0] - ($horas * 3600) - ($minutos * 60);` Aunque el resultado se apróxima creo que con eso sería necesario.